# How to change pandoc option in R Studio

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Installing package rmarkdown in R Studio you can create docx documents using a Rmd-file and pressing the `Knit Word` button.

The invoked command is then:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS hallo.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures
--output hallo.docx --highlight-style tango
```

**Question**

How to add other options? I want to add:

```
--filter ./pandoc-word-pagebreak
```

to get:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS hallo.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --filter ./pandoc-word-pagebreak
    --output hallo.docx --highlight-style tango
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pandoc_args` in your yaml front matter:

```
---
title: "Mytitle"
output:
  word_document:
    pandoc_args: [ 
      "--filter", "./pandoc-word-pagebreak" 
    ]
---
```

See the documentation [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#pandoc-arguments)

Comment: Documentation now is here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#pandoc-arguments